# Live USB boot from the Ubuntu 16.04 iso freezes and fails to operate

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, usb, iso

I want to install Ubuntu on my Dell 2400 Desktop with a 2.66GHz Pentium(R)-4 CPU and 1.11gb RAM, which now boots Windows XP Home edition (version 2002, Service Pack 3) from the hard disk drive.

When booting from the Live USB made from a downloaded ISO, it starts freezing up and eventually stops. I tried Ubuntu Budgie before that, with the same result.  I am afraid to try to install anything not knowing what's the issue.

Comment: Im using the 32 bit version.  I've made sure I met all requirements and had the right version and don't know what's the issue

Comment: I'm using 8gb SanDisk USB stick and Rufus program to write the ISO.  Question is do I need to format USB from fat32 to another format as suggested in the link you posted?

Comment: I didn't read anything about doing so before burning the ISO in the tutorial.  It just stated to use Rufus  and it would take care of writing it.

Comment: if you already reached the menu where you could select `Try Ubuntu`, your configured USB drive should be fine. but I think the default Ubuntu 16.04 image is too much for your Pentium 4 to handle since it doesn't even support 64 bit. I suggest you try one of the official lightweight flavors, either Lubuntu or Xubuntu _should_ work fine

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help.  Been tirelessly researching this issue

Comment: Can I delete 16.04 and burn a new image of a different version on the same USB stick ? Or will it not work properly?

Comment: Yes you can, burning an image to a USB stick does not affect it physically, and it doesn't differ from normal data copying to the drive. You can repeat the process of burning (using Rufus for example) as long as the stick still works i.e not damaged. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded software can be corrupted in transit, so there's a way to check and make sure what you downloaded is correct.

After you have downloaded http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.4/ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-i386.iso, you can [verify the integrity of the download](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto#Verifying_the_ISO_integrity) from within Windows before you put it on your USB flash memory drive. Download both the [SHA256SUMS file](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.4/SHA256SUMS) and the [SHA256SUMS.GPG file](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.4/SHA256SUMS.gpg) which match that download, and then make sure the ISO arrived intact by [downloading GP4WIN](https://www.gpg4win.org/) and using it to make sure everything's OK before you make the LiveUSB to boot Linux with, with the steps shown at https://www.howtogeek.com/246332/how-to-verify-a-downloaded-linux-iso-file-wasnt-tampered-with/.

However, the Ubuntu package is a little hefty for a machine with only 1.1GB of RAM, and if that should fail, I would try [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) instead, which needs less memory to run.

Answer (score 0):

Some old hardware don't support booting from USB drives but since you already reached the menu where you could select `Try Ubuntu without installing`, your USB drive's configuration should be fine. But I suppose the default Ubuntu 16.04 image (and even Ubuntu Budgie) are too much for your Pentium 4 to handle, since [it doesn't even support 64 bit instruction set](https://ark.intel.com/products/27444/Intel-Pentium-4-Processor-2_66-GHz-512K-Cache-533-MHz-FSB), thus the freezing you're experiencing. I suggest you try one of the official lightweight flavors, either [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/downloads) or [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/download) should work *fine*, with Lubuntu on the lightest side since it will run *perfectly* on a PC with [as low as 512MB of RAM and a Pentium 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_16.04_LTS).

Note that you better use a USB 2.0 port on your computer to boot the live USB, because the boot time on a USB 1.1 port (if your computer have one) will take much longer time. If you're unsure try different ports. Oh and avoid using USB Hubs when possible.